# What is the relationship between power and energy?

Tags: energy, power

What is the relationship between power and energy?

Of course, this is a very basic and fundamental question, but it's one that many people learning physics struggle with. I'm asking this to have a canonical answer to refer to within the site to refer to when answering other questions.

Previous questions on the topic either refer to specific scenarios (like [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/333717/22927)) or failed to get a general answer (like [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163536/22927)).

I'd prefer an answer that can be understood by a high school student without knowing calculus, rather than just a formula as in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/333721/22927), although it's also good to include the integral or differential formulas.

Edit: The system has forced me to edit to explain why the previous question doesn't meet my needs, but I've already explained above why the proposed duplicate doesn't serve as a useful reference for answering this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70227/discussion-on-question-by-the-photon-what-is-the-relationship-between-power-and).

Comment: @Qmechanic, FYI, despite being closed this question just earned a "Popular Question" badge.

Comment: @Qmechanic, and now it has earned "Notable Question".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power is the amount of energy produced (or consumed) for unit of time.

For exemple, Sun's reaction produces $x$ MeV of energy per day. So, it's power is $\frac{x}{(24*60*60)} \frac{MeV}{s}$.

$\text{Power}=\frac{\text{energy}}{\text{time}}$ (more precisely $dP=\frac{dE}{dt}$)

Answer (score 1):

People already gave accurate answers. Let me try to give you some perspective to give you some understanding of both energy and power in laymen terms.

If we want to do any work, we need energy. Keep your engine running, or heat up food, or move blocks. All of it requires energy. We know that energy can neither be created nor be destroyed but can only be converted from one form to other.

Let's take the example of a car engine. You have fuel, you convert that chemical energy into mechanical and have an engine running. This allows your car to move, this solves our energy problem when we figure out which type of energy can we use to make our car move. Now at some point in time, you will run out of fuel. So the more important question for you is - When will you run out of fuel? You have limited fuel a.k.a. limited amount of energy, so if we know how much energy we use per second, or per minute, we will know when will we run out of our fuel. This is where power comes in. It's simply a calculation of how many units of energy you are using per unit of time. Depending on the situation, you can decide to use whatever units you like for energy and time. But essentially its energy/time. Work is also a form of energy so sometimes you get questions like -
how much work can you do per second?

Essentially, the amount of power tells us the amount of fuel we are consuming that will determine the amount of fuel we need to keep providing for the engine to work and our car to keep moving.

One more thing. For example, if we have 250 horsepower engine, what that means is that particular engine has an upper limit. No matter how much fuel you supply, that's the absolute max of the performance you are going to get. Even if your tank is full, there is a limit on how fast you can accelerate and how fast you can possibly go.

To sum up-
Energy: how much total work we are doing.
Power: how fast are we doing our work.